# angular multiple interceptors in app.config

Tags: angularjs, interceptor

in my angular app, I want to add informations to all calls to an external API.

To do so, I use interceptors that I call from within app.config.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', ... , function($httpProvider, ...){      
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('globalInterceptorService');
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
}]);
```

It works fine when I only use one interceptor. But when I use 2 of them (as in the example above) the action of one gets overridden by the other.

Any idea about how to deal with multiple interceptors? Maybe is it recommended to have only 1? Any help is much appreciate.

Interceptor 1 :

```
function globalInterceptorService ($q, localStorageService) {

  var service = {};

  var _request = function (config) {

    config.headers = config.headers || {};

    var AreaId = localStorageService.get('AreaId');
    if (AreaId) {

      config.headers.AreaId = 'AreaId ' + AreaId;

    }

    return config;
  };

  service.request = _request;

  return service;
}
```

Interceptor 2 :

```
function authInterceptorService ($q, $location, localStorageService) {

  var service = {};

  var _request = function (config) {

    config.headers = config.headers || {};

    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
    if (authData) {
      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
    }

    return config;
  };

  service.request = _request;

  return service;
}
```

Comment: All seems okay, and it's okay to use several interceptors. Are you using `$provide.factory` to declare your interceptors ? Can you try         `console.log(JSON.stringify(config.headers));` before `return config;` in both interceptors to have a better view of what is happening ?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(config.headers)) : 

"{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","AreaId":"tst"}"

Comment: You don't have any return of the console.log in "authInterceptorService" ?

Comment: Nop. I think the answer below could explain it. But then it leads to the question how to inject the required services in the app,config :/

Comment: Inject in $provide in app.config in order to use  ̀$provide.factory` inside your config function and correcly push your interceptors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should push the function, not its string name.

```
function globalInterceptorService($q, localStorageService){...}
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(globalInterceptorService);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/tbhobfbu

Or

```
function globalInterceptorService($q, localStorageService){...}
$provide.factory('globalInterceptorService',globalInterceptorService)
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('globalInterceptorService');
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/tbhobfbu/2/

It's well described in the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

Comment: A problem with what you suggest is that in order to push the function, I need to inject the service in app.config and this seems not possible

Comment: You don't need to inject service into `app.config`. You inject it into interceptor function. http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/tbhobfbu/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can first try it out on monday as I am not at work until then.